# Adding image to a node_modules packpage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, node-modules

I'm using a fork of a react-native module (React-native-pjsip) and need use an image in a notification with this:

```java
NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "")
    .setContentTitle("My app Name")
    .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_launcher)
    .setContentText("The app is running on foreground!")
    .setContentIntent(openAppPendingIntent)
    .addAction(action)
    .setOngoing(true)
    .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MIN);
```

The problem is: 
There is no drawable folder, and i didn't have sucess creating one.

The ic_launcher file is my own icon of the app, and the notification works well, the only one problem is the custom icon itself.

The error when i compile is:

```
error: cannot find symbol
                .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                                                ^
  symbol:   variable ic_launcher
  location: class drawable
```

[EDIT]: The solution was: Use "R.drawable.ic_launcher" instead of "android.R.drawable.ic_launcher"